# Complex MySQL-Query: Get Name of object, and count and average-value of all grandchildren

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have ratings, which represent a rating of a product.
These ratings have a value (Integer between 1 and 5), a product_id and a rating_type_id.

Ratings have a many-to-one relationship to rating_types. rating_types have a many_to_one relationship to rating_categories. Meaning: `one rating_category` has `several rating_types` and `one rating_types` has `several ratings`.

In addition every product has a many-to-many relationship to rating_categories. Meaning, that given product can only be rated by ratings, whose rating_type belongs to these rating_categories.

For a given product_id, I would like to retrieve for every rating_category, the category-Name, the count of all ratings and the average of all ratings. These ratings have the product_id as a foreign key, and have to have a rating_type as a foreignkey, whose rating_type has a rating_category as a foreignKey.

This is my Query so far, but it is wrong:

```
SELECT rc.name, rc.rating_category_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) as count, AVG(value) as average
   FROM rating
   WHERE rating_id IN (
     SELECT r.rating_id
     FROM rc // I want to reference the same rating_category rc as above
     LEFT JOIN rating_type rt
     ON rating_category_id
     LEFT JOIN rating r
     ON rating_type_id
   )
  )
FROM rating_category_4_product rc4p
LEFT JOIN rating_category rc
ON rating_category_id
WHERE rc4p.product_id = {$productId}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, not tested though.

```
SELECT
  rc4p.product_id,
  rc.rating_category_id,
  rc.name,
  COUNT(r.rating_id),
  AVG(r.value)
FROM
  rating_category_4_product rc4p,
  rating_category rc,
  rating_type rt,
  rating r
WHERE
  r.rating_type_id = rt.rating_type_id
  AND rt.rating_category_id = rc.rating_category_id
  AND rc.rating_category_id = rc4p.rating_category_id
  AND rc4p.product_id = {$productId}
GROUP BY
  rc4p.product_id,
  rc.rating_category_id,
  rc.name
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but isnt the performance really bad? Shouldnt you use Joins?

Comment: Performance would be as good as db optimizer which evolves with db engine improvements. Grouping is not slow when you have indexes on all tables' primary keys. Additionally you can use explain http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html to check performance.